# Error while comparing data fetched from the table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, error-handling, comparison

I am not sure what's wrong, but it gives the error message- `Error1: "Notice: Undefined index: user_type"` and Error2: `"Notice: Undefined index: user_approved"`, while there exists a table userdetails which has columns with the name user_type and user_approved.

NOTE: The code may be incomplete, but it has nothing to do with the error, I have only pasted the code for reference, the concern is the error.

```
 if(isset($_POST['login_btn'])){

                // define variables and set to empty values
                $email = $pwd = "";
                $query1 = $result1 = "";
                $error = FALSE;
                $usertype = $status = "";
                $combo = FALSE;

                $email = validate_input($_POST['user_name']);
                $pwd = validate_input($_POST['user_pwd']);

                include_once("includes/connection.php");

                $query1 = "SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE user_email='$email' AND user_pwd='$pwd'";

                $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1);

                if (!$result1) {
                    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
                    exit;
                }
                else{
                    while($array1= mysqli_fetch_row($result1)){
                        $combo=TRUE;
                        $usertype=$array1['user_type']; **//Error1**
                        $status=$array1['user_approved']; **//Error2**
                    };
                }
```

Comment: Use `$usertype=$array1[0];$status=$array1[1];` because see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset starting from 0 (zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mysqli_fetch_row** return  result row as an enumerated array

you can use **mysqli_fetch_assoc** to get

```
while($array1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the name of the table columns in your $array1 you have to use

```
$array1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

eg:

```
while($array1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
   $combo=TRUE;
   $usertype=$array1['user_type']; **//Error1**
   $status=$array1['user_approved']; **//Error2**
};
```

For your question, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

> Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an
>   enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset
>   starting from 0 (zero). Each subsequent call to this function will
>   return the next row within the result set, or NULL if there are no
>   more rows.

So it stored as index as 0, 1, 2 etc...

```
while($array1= mysqli_fetch_row($result1)){
   $combo=TRUE;
    $usertype=$array1[0];
    $status=$array1[1];
};
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

select the exact columns in query instead of * and then use below.
$usertype=$array1[0];
 $status=$array1[1];
Or you need to use the index of those columns for e.g. if thye are 3rd and 4th columns of your sql result then use $array1[2] and $array1[3]